# Passing multiple arguments within apply function

Tags: r, apply

I am trying to pass 2 arguments for a user-defined function within the FUN argument of an apply function, as in the below example:

```
mat <- matrix(NA, nrow =10, ncol=3)
mat[,1] <- runif(10, 0, 1)
mat[,2] <- runif(10, 0, 1)
mat[,3] <- runif(10, 0, 1)


roundFn <- function(indata, p){
  for (i in ncol(indata)){
    if(is.numeric(indata[,i])){
      indata[,i] <- round(indata[,i], digits = p)
    }
  } 
}

outdata <- apply(mat, 2, roundFn, indata = mat, p = 3)
```

But when I run the above code I get an error message that says:

```
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (newX[, i])
```

Any tips on how to properly use the apply function in this context would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your `roundFn` function loops through every column of `indata`, so applying it to every column with `apply` is redundant. You can either (1) apply `roundFn` directly to `mat`, or (2) redefine `roundFn` to act on a column of `mat`, and then apply it to every column with `apply`.

```
mat = replicate(3, runif(10)) #a smarter way to create a random matrix
```

First method:

```
roundFn <- function(indata, p){
  for (i in 1:ncol(indata)){ #here you missed the "1:" before "ncol(indata)"
    if(is.numeric(indata[,i])){
      indata[,i] <- round(indata[,i], digits = p)
    }
  }
  return(indata) #you forgot to say what your function should return
}

outdata <- roundFn(mat, 3)
```

Second method:

```
roundFn <- function(indata.col, p){ #now, it receives a column
  if(is.numeric(indata.col)){
    return(round(indata.col, digits = p))
  }
}

outdata <- apply(mat, 2, roundFn, p = 3)
```

As @Allan Cameron and @M-- pointed out in the comments, `roundFn` is really similar to  `round`, the only difference is that it only applies to numeric columns. Thus, you can get the same output from:

Using base R:

```
apply(mat[,apply(mat, 2, is.numeric)], 2, round, digits = 3)
```

Using dplyr/tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
mutate(as_tibble(mat), across(where(is.numeric), round, digits = 3))
```

Comment: This is right. Notice though that effectively `roundFn` becomes functionally the same as plain old `round`, except it has a `p` argument instead of `digits` . You would get the same output by simply doing `apply(mat, 2, round, digits = 3)`

Comment: @AllanCameron although `roundFn` checks for `is.numeric`!

Comment: I added both your contributions to the answer, thanks!